# Grab view from touch event

Tags: iphone, uiview, uitouch

i have a quick question,

I have a view with multiple subviews.

In my view i have touches began etc..

is there a way to retrieve a subview from the touches began without having to detect the location from the touch and then have a big if else to c which subview is in that specific area.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is instead of calculating the touch position from the super view. Sub class the child view and get the touch position form there only and convert the point with respect to the super view.

Comment: Thanks but when you mean subclass, do you mean that I should capture the touch events from the subview ?

Comment: yes, after getting the touch point from subclass, convert that point to superview and change the origin of the subview.

Answer (score 0):

The method you want is the UIView instance method `-(UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`. That will return you the lowest-level subview containing `point`.

So you get the point of your touch, pass it to that method of your biggest container UIView, and get back a handle to the frontmost subview that got touched. Easy peasy.

Comment: Thanks for that, so basically use hittest on the parent view to get the lowest level view. Cheers! Trying that now.

Comment: Hello I tried it but it is returning the same view. i.e the parent view instead of the subview.